# How to set up a recurrence relation for a given algorithm or program

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

How to set up a recurrence relation for a given algorithm or program?
For example we want to set up recurrence relation for this algorithm:

```
if n = 1
then return 1
else return Q(n-1) + n * n * n
```

See the link:
[cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/teaching/cs3530/sessions/session07.html](http://cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/teaching/cs3530/sessions/session07.html)

On this page we have this algorithm:

```
if n = 1 then return 1 
else return Q(n-1) + n * n * n
```

They said We set up a recurrence relation for the number of multiplications as:

```
M(1) = 0 M(n) = M(n-1) + 2
```

what's that mean ?

Comment: Isn't this a recurrence relation itself?

Comment: http://www.cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/teaching/cs3530/sessions/session07.html
On this page we have 

    if n = 1
       then return 1
       else return Q(n-1) + n * n * n
this algorithm

and they said 
We set up a recurrence relation for the number of multiplications:

    M(1) = 0
    M(n) = M(n-1) + 2

what's that mean ?

Comment: If this is your question, I'm editing the original question and writing the answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

This already IS a recurrencr equation.
Written mathematically:

```
Q(n) = Q(n-1)+n^3
n0=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, anything that is evaluated using the value(s) calculated beforehand from the same function is termed as `recurrence` and this relation is `recurrence relation`.

So, the algorithm that you mention is the recurrence relation in itself, as it uses the value of `Q(n-1)`, to evaluate `Q(n)`.

However we manipulate a value to get the next (or desired) value, is the recurrence relation. A few examples of recurrences can be:

- Fibonacci series:

  F(0)=0, F(1)=1,
  F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
- Factorial:

  F(0)=1,
  F(n) = n * F(n-1)

etc.

So, here we need to find the recurrence of number of multiply operations that will be performed in evaluation of `Q(n)`

Since Q(1) = 1, and we know Q(1) directly, there is no multiply operation involved. So,

```
M(0) = 0
```

Any subsequent evaluation of Q involves 2 multiply operations:

```
Q(n) = Q(n-1) + n*n*n
```

So, there is one `+` operation and 2 `*` operations. So, we can write:

```
M(n) = M(n-1) + 2
```

So, complete recurrence will be:

```
M(0) = 0 (base case)
M(n) = M(n-1) + 2 (recurrence)
```

Actually, if you look clearly, there is no need of establishing a recurrence relation as number of `*` operations can be given directly by:

```
M(n) = 2*n,
```

And, this is not a recurrence relation, as it is not evaluated using previous values of the series.

Comment: Q(n) = Q(n-1) + n*n*n
So, there is one + operation and 2 * operations. So, we can write:
M(n) = M(n-1) + 2

As you said there is one + operation and 2 * so don't we will write 
M(n) = M(n-1) + 3 as we have 3 operation in total ?

Comment: The question has asked recurrence relation for number of multiplication operations.

Comment: so if we want to calculate time of an algorithm we will write recurrence relation and then solve it using iteration method or with any other method 
so in this process we will count total operation ?

Comment: There is a method called `Master's method` to calculate time complexity of any recurrence relation. Also, there are other methods like `recurrence tree`, etc. But for that, you have to establish a recurrence on time. Here, the recurrence relation is for the procedure, and not on time. Time recurrence for this case will be: `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)`